# Is there anyway to pull events from the Facebook Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, facebook-php-sdk, endpoint

I have a travel app that, *used to*, pull events from Facebook using the `GET /search?q=tokyo&type=event` enpoint. I understand this endpoint is now deprecated per [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/?translation&hc_location=ufi#search-4-4).

So I started to use this endpoint from my *Facebook PHP SDK*: `GET /me/events` where in order to pull an event from the API, I'd have to manually set my self as ***going*** on my personal Facebook account. Just yesterday I noticed that it now returns 200 response with an empty JSON.

I also saw [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/?translation&hc_location=ufi#login_4_4) post that suggested that access to `user_events` will face more scrutiny in the **App Review** process. However, I already went through an app review last year and I can see this in my dashboard:

[image]

Hovering over the green circle says: ***Live and Available to all Users.***
So what's wrong?

Also, I can see this note in the [App Review process docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit):

> You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used by you or
>   by a reduced number of people. Any account listed in the Roles tab in
>   your App Dashboard, such as admins, developers and testers, can access
>   all permissions and generate a user or page access token.
>
> You can use any of these accounts to test your app and create a
>   screencast.

And that's exactly what I do, I pull the events that belong to my account, that is registered as a ***Developer*** on the app's dashboard. However, trying to pull my own events even from the Graph Explorer returns empty JSON.

My last resort seems to be to resubmit an ***App Review***. However, given that I already went through late last year, I receive this warning when clicking ***Start Over***:

[image]

Is it safe to do or will current permissions be revoked in any way? If so how long will this process take?

**AND MOST IMPORTANTLY**

How do I pull events right now in the wake of these updates, and is my issue really related to Cambridge Analytica incident or am I missing something? And do I really have to resubmit for an app review?

Comment: Right now: You don’t. Do you have to submit for review: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! what about the" Are you sure you want to discard" warning message? And will the events endpoint work afterwards?

Comment: No, it will only work after your app has been reviewed again. But you can not currently submit for that, the process is on hold.